# Why in this case use Interface over Abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I was reading a blog post here: http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/02/12/learn-this-when-to-use-an-abstract-class-and-an-interface/

```
public interface Actor{
   Performance say(Line l);
}
public interface Director{
   Movie direct(boolean goodmovie);
}
public interface ActorDirector extends Actor, Director{
...
}
```

It says: 
In reality, there are Actors who are also Directors. If we are using interfaces rather than abstract classes.*We could achieve the same thing using abstract classes. Unfortunately the alternative would require up to **2^n** (where n is the number of **attributes**) possible combinations in order to support all possibilities.*

Question: why abstract class is better here ? and why 2^n ?

```
public abstract class ActorDirector implements Actor,Director{
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you asking why an interface is better, or why an abstract class is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the post: the author is not arguing that an abstract class is better in this situation - on the contrary, he is arguing that an interface is a better fit.

As far as `2^n` (or more precisely `2^n-1`) goes, the number comes from realization that if you have `n` orthogonal behavior contracts, you can make `2^n-1` non-empty combinations from them. If you use interfaces to add contracts to classes that implement them, you need only as many interfaces as there are behaviors: the user will be able to make combinations of behaviors that he chooses to implement, up to `2^n-1`. If you were to try achieving the same flexibility with abstract classes, you would end up creating not only your desired implementations, but also all the *intermediate ones required all the way to a single root*, because Java lets you inherit classes only one at a time.

Comment: I don't think one can achieve the required semantics, no matter *how many* abstract classes one has.  If there exist abilities A, B, and C, and one consumer needs objects with abilities AB, one needs BC, and one needs AC, there is no way to define a single class which can satisfy all three consumers except by requiring that one of the above consumers must demand that class, rather than a class which would more narrowly fulfill its needs.

Comment: @supercat I think that's the point the post was trying to make: in order to let users make all combinations of all behaviors, the authors would need to provide abstract classes not only for A, B, and C, but also for AB, AC, BC, and ABC.

Comment: My example was overcomplicated.  Assume there are just two abstract classes X and Y.  Further, suppose there's a concrete class which has all the abilities implied by both classes.  Despite its abilities, the class cannot derive from both abstract classes.  If it derives from X, it will not be usable by code expecting a Y, and vice versa.  No matter how many classes one defines, one still gets stuck.

Comment: @supercat Oh, of course the author of such library would not be able to rely on inheritance to share implementations! He would need to make a lot of copying, which of course defeats the purpose of having abstract classes in the first place. In your `ABC` example, the author would need to provide A, B, C, AB (inherit A, copy B), AC (inherit A, copy C), BC (inherit B, copy C), and ABC (inherit AB, copy C). He could do it in other ways, too - for example, in AB he could inherit B and copy A, but that does not make a difference: there will be a lot of code duplication.

Comment: What good would all that do?  The only way a single object instance would be able to satisfy A and B would be if A were to inherit from B (requiring all inheritors of A to advertise ability B, whether or not they actually supported it) or vice versa.  I'm not clear how having an exponential number of classes would help anything.  An exponential explosion of interfaces could actually be theoretically helpful, but is in reality not needed since one can generally define composite interfaces for those combinations that are actually helpful.

Comment: @supercat You are correct, this is precisely what the author of the post was saying: specifying behaviors of classes though interfaces is easy, but trying to do the same through abstract classes is useless.

Comment: We're certainly agreed on that point.  My point was that I don't see the relevance to saying one would need 2^n classes to handle every combination of attributes.  One would need 2^n interfaces if classes could provide an arbitrary combination of attributes, consumers could require an arbitrary combination of attributes, and one wanted to allow classes to be passed in type-safe manner to those consumers, and only those consumers, whose requirements they could satisfy.  In practice, of course, one usually doesn't try for quite that level of precision.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot inherit from more than one class (abstract or not), but can implement multiple interfaces

If you were to create abstract classes, you will need one for every combination (n atributes: 2^n possible combination) -- to ensure that each combination can be inherited from, if needed.

If you are using interfaces, you only need to define the n interface (one for each attribute) and implement them as needed.

Comment: +1 Which why you might need `2^n` combinations of abstract classes, instead of `n` interfaces.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: What can one do with 2^n combinations of abstract classes which one cannot do without?  An abstract class which inherits abstract class `X` and duplicates all the features of abstract class `Y` but does not inherit from it will not be substitutable for `Y`.  One could define 2^n such classes for different combinations of base abstract classes, but I don't see such a thing as being either necessary or useful.

Answer (score 1):

The question you need to answer when deciding on whether you need an `Abstract` class or not is simple;

Is there any common **implementation** of any of the methods shared between any of the classes that implement either of these interfaces? If that is **yes** then you would put that implementation in an `AbstractClass`.

If that is **no** then you would just combine the two into a single `Interface` and have all the implementing classes provide their custom, non-shared implementations.

There is definitely an argument to be made to do both. Have a super-interface that allows for working around single inheritance restrictions, as well as also having an `Abstract` implementation of that super-interface as well, to provide high-cohesion for any shared default implementations of any of the methods in the interface.

These decisions are easier the more experience you gain solving these problems incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance has two parts:

1. A derived class can regard public or protected methods or fields of its parents as though they are its own.

   A derived-type object may be substituted for a base-type object in most contexts where the latter is requested.

A class which implements an interface receives only the latter benefit, but a class which inherits from an abstract class achieves both.  On the other hand, with that benefit comes a restriction: because it's only possible for a class to regard one other class's methods and fields as its own, it's only possible for a class to inherit from one abstract class.  By contrast, a class can implement (and thus be substitutable for) any number of interfaces.

Don't concern yourself with the combinatorial explosion of abstract classes.  Suppose some vehicles can Steer (e.g. CompactCar), others can AttachFollower (e.g. a RailwayLocomotive), and some can do both (e.g. PickupTruck).  It should be possible for a `PickupTruck` to satisfy code needing a vehicle that can `Steer`, as well as code needing a vehicle that can `AttachFollower`.  If `Steer` and `AttachFollower` were both abstract classes, however, there would be no way to declare `PickupTruck` so one instance could perform both functions.  The best one could do would be to define a 'SteerableAndHitchable`abstract class which inerits from`Steerable`and includes a`TrailerHitch`member of type`Attachable`, but that sort of thing is icky even with just two abilities.  Adding more abilities in type-safe manner will not only require an exploding number of classes; it will require an expanding number of properties for each class.